# only one object of an element present several time in xml file

Tags: python, lxml

I am parsing an xml file using lxml.objectify but just one object of a element is present in the root object while there is two in the xml file

xml element file

```
<installationsVisibles>
    <installation hauteur="2.3" distance="1.00">
        <type>TELEPHONIE</type>
    </installation>
    <installation hauteur="4" distance="10">
        <type>RADIO</type>
    </installation>
</installationsVisibles>


fileobject = open('TestRapportValid.xml')
tree = objectify.parse(fileobject)
root=tree.getroot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ObjectifiedElement.getchildren()](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement-class.html#getchildren) method. E.g.:

```
for child in root.getchildren():
    ...
```